# How to pass the search parameters in the link to print

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How to pass the search parameters in the link to print.

I have a method `#index` controller `#TicketsController`

```
def index
  @search = current_account.searches.find_by(id: params[:search_id])

  @q = policy_scope(Ticket).ransack(params[:q])

  if params[:q].blank? && params[:advanced_search].blank? || params[:q]&.to_unsafe_h&.length == 1 && params[:q][:s].present?
    @q.add_default_condition('status', 'in', 'open')
    session[:last_ticket_search] = nil
  else
    session[:last_ticket_search] = {q: params[:q]}
    if params[:advanced_search].present?
      session[:last_ticket_search].merge!(advanced_search: 't', selected_columns: params[:selected_columns])
      session[:last_ticket_search].merge!(params[:search_id].present? ? {search_id: params[:search_id]} : {commit: 'Apply'})
    end
  end

  @selected_columns = selected_columns
  @tickets = @q.result.select('tickets.*')
                      .includes(:account, :ticket_responses, :assignee, :tags)
                      .order('tickets.created_at DESC')
                      .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: per_page('tickets'))
end
```

I need to make a page for printing all objects.
For this I made the link `Print` in `tickets/index.html.erb

```
<a class="btn btn-primary print-button" href="<%= tickets_path(variant: :print) %>" target="_blank" title="Print ticket" data-tooltip data-placement="bottom">
  <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
</a>
```

The point is that if you click on it will open the whole list of objects here, all is well. But if I use `search`, I will generate the list of all objects. I need a list of objects I defined in the search. So how do I pass a  search parameter in the controller to generate the print page?

I tried that.

```
<%= tickets_path(q: params[:q], advanced_search: params[:advanced_search], variant: :print) %>
```

But the controller does not share parameters and accepts a string.

need: `"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=><ActionController::Parameters {"assignee_id_eq"=>"", "status_in"=>"closed", "ticket_type_eq"=>"", "simple_search"=>""}`

I get: `{"q"=>"assignee_id_eq=&simple_search=&status_in=closed&ticket_type_eq=", "variant"=>"print", "controller"=>"tickets", "action"=>"index"}`

Comment: You mean you dont want to search again and how do you store the results in the mean time or just how to pass a query parameter to a link_helper?

Comment: just how to pass a query parameter to a link_helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an instance variable with your required parameters parsed into a hash which will be available in the view:

```
def new
  @search_params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query params[:q]
  ...
end
```

and in the view:

```
<%= tickets_path(q: @search_params[:q], advanced_search: params[:advanced_search], variant: :print) %>
```

Comment: but I still get the row with the parameters. `@print_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"q"=>"assignee_id_eq=&simple_search=&status_in=closed&ticket_type_eq=", "variant"=>"print", "controller"=>"tickets", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>`

Comment: Ok i start to get what you mean.

Comment: I edited the answer, check it out. Basically you just need to parse a query string to a hash and then use that